# Ternary Operator React Native in StyleSheet

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, tsx, react-native-stylesheet

Is there a way to use the Ternary Operator in the `StyleSheet`?

Currently, my `TextInput` looks as such:

**.tsx**

```
<TextInput
  defaultValue={selectedEvent ? selectedEvent.title : ""}
  style={[
    styles.textInput,
    { color: colorScheme === "dark" ? "#ffffff" : "#000000" },
  ]}
  onChangeText={inputChangeHandler}
/>
```

**StyleSheet**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 15,
    paddingVertical: 4,
    paddingHorizontal: 2,
  },
})
```

It'd be nice not to combine internal and external styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
In you **TextInput**:

```
style={styles.textInput(colorScheme)}
```

And in **StyleSheet**

```
textInput:(colorScheme)=> ({
  borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  marginBottom: 15,
  paddingVertical: 4,
  paddingHorizontal: 2,
  color: colorScheme === "dark" ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
}),
```

[Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@tayyabreact/switch)

Comment: Magic. Looks interesting, props for that, and it (partially) works. The compiler complains *a lot* and this technique drops a few of my styles hmm

Comment: I'm intrigued. Do you have a working demo of this? It makes sense, logically, but I wasn't able to verify/validate it in a running example (RN is sometime very illogical).

Comment: @DrewReese Sure, I've added an example.

Comment: Ah, I see, works on native only.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, it seem so.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, because the question was if it's possible, and the answer is yes. However, I'm getting lots of compiler warnings (on `strict` & not `strict` for `TypeScript`) with this setup. Thanks for the [Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@tayyabreact/switch). It helped out, I'm posting in the next comment my other compiler's long warning.

Warning1: `This expression is not callable.
  No constituent of type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle' is callable.ts(2349)
(property) textInput: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle`. In addition, as said, it cuts partially my styles...

Comment: Warning2: `Type '(colorScheme: string) => { borderBottomColor: string; borderBottomWidth: number; color: string; marginBottom: number; paddingVertical: number; paddingHorizontal: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle'.
  Value of type '(colorScheme: string) => { borderBottomColor: string; borderBottomWidth: number; color: string; marginBottom: number; paddingVertical: number; paddingHorizontal: number; }' has no properties in common with type 'ImageStyle'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2322)`

Comment: However, with this amount of warnings, I'll keep my solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

In StyleSheet you can't use ternary.
But what you can is combine ternary and stylesheet like that:

```
<div
    style={checkIfActive(props.position, 1)
        ? { ...styles.circle, ...styles.circleActive }
        : { ...styles.circle, ...styles.circleUnactive }}
/>
```

And you CSS can be:

```
circle: {
    width: '80%',
    margin: 'auto',
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ffffff83',
},
circleUnactive: {
    backgroundColor: '#40c5ee4e',
},
circleActive: {
    backgroundColor: '#40c5ee',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The `StyleSheet` is generating static styling "classes", but you can define a light/dark class to use and append it to the array. It's not much different than what you've done already though.

Example:

```
<TextInput
  defaultValue={selectedEvent ? selectedEvent.title : ''}
  style={[
    styles.textInput,
    styles[colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'],
  ]}
  onChangeText={console.log}
/>

...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  textInput: {
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 15,
    paddingVertical: 4,
    paddingHorizontal: 2,
  },
  light: {
    color: '#000',
  },
  dark: {
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Here's a running [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/tactless-peach) of the above code.